# Trouble with local iCloud services

Tags: icloud, password, restart

I reset my password for iCloud recently and everything went pretty smoothly. My mac still connects to iCloud and the password to log in has also been changed. However whenever I restart my computer, all of the different iCloud services request my password again, and only accept my old password. There are about 10 pop- up boxes, here are some of them:

[image]
[image]

How do I notify these services that the password has been changed so that I do not have to go through this process every time I restart my machine?

(As a side note, I know that my mac connects to iCloud because iCloud Drive does update when I add folder to the iCloud Drive folder on my mac.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called Apple tech support today and got the following answer. It seems to be working so far.

1. Navigate to the `Library` folder (The easiest way is to go to the `Finder` top menu bar, hold down `Option` on the `Go` submenu and you should see it come up)
2. Delete the `Keychains` folder
3. Go to iCloud in `Preferences` and sign back in

Hope this helps!